# DateTimeOffset Error: UTC offset of local dateTime does not match the offset argument

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to create a small method that converts the time from one timezone to another. I thought it would be simple enough, but when I deploy it I get this error `The UTC Offset of the local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument.` My guess is that it's because the server is not in the same timezone as the user which is not helpful since this would be used from around the world.

```
public object ConvertDate(DateTime inputTime, string fromOffset, string toZone)
{
    var fromTimeOffset = new TimeSpan(0, - int.Parse(fromOffset), 0);
    var to = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(toZone);
    var offset = new DateTimeOffset(inputTime, fromTimeOffset);
    var destination = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(offset, to); 
    return destination.DateTime;
}
```

Where `fromOffset` is a number, converted to timespan from the users timezone and `toZone` is the name of the zone we're converting to.
The error occurs on this line `var offset = new DateTimeOffset(inputTime, fromTimeOffset);`

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: what are the sample values for `inputTime, fromTimeOffset` that you are passing

Comment: an example could be: `inputTime = 28/03/2016 6:09:49 PM` and `fromTimeOffset = 13hrs`

Comment: If you ever find yourself saying "I thought it would be simple enough..." in regards to the C# `DateTime`, it's worth reading Jon Skeet's (in)famous "What's wrong with DateTime anyway?" post about the birth of the NodaTime library: http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.-ctor#System_DateTimeOffset__ctor_System_DateTime_System_TimeSpan_) for why the exception is being thrown:

> **ArgumentException**: `dateTime.Kind` equals `Local` and `offset` does not equal the offset of the system's local time zone.

The `DateTime` argument that you receive has its `Kind` property set to `Local`. The simplest way around this problem is to set the `Kind` to `Unspecified`.

```
public object ConvertDate(DateTime inputTime, string fromOffset, string toZone)
{
    // Ensure that the given date and time is not a specific kind.
    inputTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(inputTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

    var fromTimeOffset = new TimeSpan(0, - int.Parse(fromOffset), 0);
    var to = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(toZone);
    var offset = new DateTimeOffset(inputTime, fromTimeOffset);
    var destination = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(offset, to); 
    return destination.DateTime;
}
```

Comment: Ah that solved it thanks, I did read the documentation but found it a bit hard to interpret tbh

Comment: This is so ridiculous, it makes working with DateTimeOffsets a nightmare. If someone is *explicitly* setting the offset on a new DTO, might they have realized we wanted it to have an offset and thus allow it? And might they have realized that in most cases, the setting of the original DateTime.Kind was not in our hands? And worse, that the constant assumption of using the local time (sorry, that is HORRIBLE for servers) gets us in this situation in the first place? This is such a frustrating framework decision that causes lots of pain.

Comment: Silly MS documentation specified that the ArgumentException was due to the Kind being mismatched but couldn't bother telling us how to go about changing it so we don't try changing it directly only to find it only has a getter!

Comment: You can set the Culture for the thread and then everything just uses the right culture. It's a shame that .NET won't let you set the Time Zone similarly and have the DateTimes "just work". For example, DateTime.Now would return the time offset to the configured TimeZone. It would make it so easy to "relocate".

Answer (score 19):

Here's an extension method I use to get around this incredibly frustrating framework decision. See notes, the best and most performant way to handle this is to use the ticks constructor of `DateTimeOffset`, instead of having to allocate another intermediate `DateTime` just to change it's `Kind` property.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a DateTime to a DateTimeOffset, without risking any onerous exceptions
    /// the framework quite unfortunately throws within the DateTimeOffset constructor, 
    /// such as they do when the source DateTime's Kind is not set to UTC. The best and 
    /// most performant way around this, which we do herein, is to simply construct the 
    /// new DateTimeOffset with the overload that excepts Ticks. Also, we will simply 
    /// return <see cref="DateTimeOffset.MinValue"/> if the source DateTime was 
    /// <see cref="DateTime.MinValue"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt">Source DateTime.</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Offset</param>
    public static DateTimeOffset ToDateTimeOffset(this DateTime dt, TimeSpan offset)
    {
        // adding negative offset to a min-datetime will throw, this is a 
        // sufficient catch. Note however that a DateTime of just a few hours can still throw
        if (dt == DateTime.MinValue)
            return DateTimeOffset.MinValue;

        return new DateTimeOffset(dt.Ticks, offset);
    }

    public static DateTimeOffset ToDateTimeOffset(this DateTime dt, double offsetInHours = 0)
        => ToDateTimeOffset(dt, offsetInHours == 0 ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.FromHours(offsetInHours));
```

Comment: Very good solution!